# Counting unique values in column A based on criteria in column B

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would appreciate some assistance with crafting a formula that will count the number of unique text values in column A, that have a certain value in column B.

For example, if I wanted to count all unique fruits (Column A) that are **Yuck** (Column B), the output would equal 2 (Orange and Pear).

```
Column A       Column B  
Apple          Yum 
Orange         Yuck  
Pear           Yuck  
Pear           Yuck
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(FREQUENCY(MATCH(A:A&B:B,A:A&"Yuck",0),ROW(A:A)-ROW(A1)+1)>0))
```

---

### Explanations :

`Frequency` will count unique values that derive from the `Match`

`Match` is used to get the position of each item in the Data and only returns the first match of a duplicate item which appear more then once in the Data

The bins array of the Frequency is built from `ROW(A:A)-ROW(A1)+1` to result in a sequential array like `{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10}`

the `--` before frequency to return 1 when the >0 is `True`

`Sumproduct` will sum the 1

A:A&B:B is the value to match with `A:A&"Yuck"` : 
AppleYuck, OrangeYuck, OrangeYum to Match with AppleYuck, OrangeYuck ...
and return the row number

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieved the desired results via the following formula:

=SUMPRODUCT((B:B="Yum")/IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A:A,B:B,"Yum")=0,1,COUNTIFS(A:A,A:A&"",B:B,"Yum")))

Answer (score 0):

**You need an Array Formula to solve the issue:**

[image]

- An Array Formula in Cell `C46`, finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.

  ```
  =CEILING(SUM(SUMPRODUCT(($A$40:$A$46=A40)*($B$40:$B$46=B40))/(COUNTIFS($A$40:$A$46,A40,$B$40:$B$46,B40)+($A$40:$A$46<>A40)+($B$40:$B$46<>B40))),1)
  ```

*You may adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*